# Sql trigger doesn't work but doesn't give any error

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop, database-trigger

I made a trigger on prestashop to change the active attribute of a product when it's out of stock:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_active AFTER UPDATE ON ps_stock_available
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE 
          ps_product_shop 
     SET 
          active=0 
     WHERE 
          id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE quantity=0);
END
```

And it doesn't give me any error so it should work but the active attribute never changes, even when I set a product's quantity to zero.

Edit: after many attempts, I found out my trigger wasn't called after the right update. Here is my code, it works perfectly now.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `change_active_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `ps_product`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
      UPDATE 
           ps_product_shop 
      SET 
           active=0 
      WHERE 
          id_product IN(SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE quantity=0);
END
```

Comment: Have you tried to see if you even get inside this trigger?

Comment: No, but how can I do that?

Comment: OPTION 1: you can set a print statement  above your update query (print "here"). This will only show if you have a console or sql query software. OPTION 2: update your table by passing it an explicit id. and see if the value for that id will change (where id_product = 1234...) .

Comment: Okay i tried passing an explicit id and turns out that it works 1/5 times. I tried several times and it worked only once, the rest of the time it didn't do anything.

Comment: I changed it back to the original trigger, and for one product it worked and for another it didn't.

Comment: It only worked the first time? Did you make sure you change the value back?

Comment: Yes it only worked the first time and yes i changed the value back.

Comment: For test case.. Try to instead of updating values. INSERT new record into a table.. If your trigger doesn't insert record every time then you need to check why your trigger is not being called every time. At this point I'm puzzled why it works only sometime..

Comment: Question.. You want to set active =0 when you are updating quantity = 0 correct?

Comment: ok i'll try to INSERT new records instead.
And yes that's what I want to do

Comment: Okay.. Does the trigger have to be "for each row" I can write it in a different way and you can try

Comment: Yes the trigger has to be for each row. And yes if you have an idea i could definitely try it, i'm really confused over this trigger

Comment: I'll write a two triggers for you... You can ttry both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144269/discussion-between-stivan-and-hoel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statment-Level Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_active ON ps_stock_available
FOR UPDATE
BEGIN
     UPDATE 
          ps_product_shop 
     SET 
          active=0
     FROM
        inserted
     WHERE 
          ps_product_shop.id_product = inserted.id_product and
          inserted.quantity=0;
END
```

Row-Level Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_active BEFORE UPDATE ON ps_stock_available
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF(NEW.quantity = 0) THEN
     UPDATE 
          ps_product_shop 
     SET 
          active=0
     WHERE 
          ps_product_shop.id_product = NEW.id_product;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: The row level trigger works very well (and all the time), thank you!

Comment: Actually no there's still an issue. The product is deactivated but only when I modify the quantity of another product. I mean, if i put a product's quantity at zero, it's still activated. It's when I change the quantity of another product that the first is deactivated.

Comment: The dreaded backticks imply that this is MySQL and MySQL does not have statement level triggers.